# In AWK (or GAWK), how to determine where does n-th word start?

Tags: awk, gawk

Example: n=3, the input is

```
foo  bar    baz
a b c d e f g h
12  34 5 678
```

the output should be:

```
13
5
8
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest would probably be:

```
$ awk -v n=3 '{print index($0,$n)}' file
13
5
8
```

but it's error prone, and would require some checking. `$n` is the third word (or field separated by `FS` the field separator). `index` returns the position in characters where that occurrence begins. If the `FS` is default (space and then some) you'd probably want to start with a space and add one to the position:

```
$ awk -v n=3 '{print 1 + index($0," " $n)}' file
13
5
8
```

... as pointed out in the comments is also error prone to `n=1` or if the nth word matches the beginning of a prior word.

We could use GNU awk's `split`'s *seps* feature:

```
$ awk -v n=3 '{
    s=1                      # reset s to 1
    split($0,a,/ +/,b)       # split to a and separators to b
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)         # iterate to n
        s+=length(a[i] b[i]) # sum the lengths of a b
    print s                  # print the position
}' file
13
5
8
```

Comment: Alas, this is too error-prone if, for example, `$2==$n`

Comment: @user31264 Sure is. This was just a start. :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use `match` to do this:

```
$ awk 'match($0, /[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){2}/) {
    print RLENGTH + 1 
}' file
13
5
8
```

Or using a parameter with a dynamic regex:

```
$ awk -v n=3 'match($0, "[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){" n - 1 "}") { 
    print RLENGTH + 1 
}' file
13
5
8
```

This searches for optional leading blanks (spaces or tabs), followed by something non-blank, followed by something blank, `n - 1` times, where `n` is the word number. `match` sets the variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` (in this case, `RSTART == 1`). `RLENGTH` gives the length of the match, so one character after that is where the nth word starts.

Since you mentioned GNU awk, you can shorten things by using `\s` (which is actually `[[:space:]]`, but that works here too) and non-space `\S`:

```
$ awk -v n=3 'match($0, "\\s*(\\S+\\s+){" n - 1 "}") { print RLENGTH + 1 }' file
```

In dynamic regex, the backslashes themselves need to be escaped.

Comment: Thank you, the dynamic regex idea is great.

Comment: This is definitely the right approach when using the default FS and when using an FS that's a single character `X` it'd be a tweak to change `[:blank:]` to `X` and remove the leading `X*`. When using an FS that's a multi-char regexp, though, it gets a whole lot more interesting :-)!

Answer (score 1):

This will work for any field separator, including multi-char regexp, using GNU awk for the 4th arg to split():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{    
    split($0,flds,FS,seps)
    indent = 1
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        indent += length(flds[i] seps[i])
    }
    print indent
}

$ awk -v n=3 -f tst.awk file
13
5
8
```

or with multi-char strings of `.+.` or `.-.` between fields:

```
$ cat file2
foo.+.bar.-.baz
a.+.b.-.c.+.d.-.e.+.f.-.g.+.h
12.-.34.+.5.-.678

$ awk -F'[.][+-][.]' -v n=3 -f tst.awk file2
13
9
11
```

Note that since we're using `FS` as an argument to `split()` it will be treated as a dynamic regexp (i.e. one stored in a string) and so any backslashes in the `FS` would need to be doubled.

Also note that we start the counting loop at 0, not 1, because with the default FS any leading white space before flds[1] (i.e. before $1) is stored in seps[0]. flds[0] will always be empty and for non-default FS seps[0] will also be empty to no harm done including their length in all cases.